# BodyParser Express, I've got Object inside Object

Tags: express, body-parser

I am trying post some data on a server but doesn't work because I am getting something like { '{\n        "rate" : "26"\n}': '' }.

----App.js

```
const express     = require('express'),
      mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
      bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

const db            = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/invoiceAPI');
      app           = express(),
      port          = process.env.PORT || 3000,
      Rate          = require('./models/rateModel'),
      Client        = require('./models/clientModel'),
      Invoice       = require('./models/invoiceModel');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const invoiceRouter = require('./routes/invoiceRoutes')(Invoice),
      clientRouter  = require('./routes/clientRoutes')(Client),
      rateRouter    = require('./routes/rateRoutes')(Rate);

app.use('/api/invoices', invoiceRouter);
app.use('/api/clients', clientRouter);
app.use('/api/rates', rateRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Gulp is running on port ' + port);
});
```

---The rateRoutes file:

```
const express = require('express');

const rateRoutes = (Rate) => {
    const rateRouter = express.Router();

    rateRouter.route('/')
      .get((req,res) => {
          Rate.find((err,rates) => {
            if(err){
              res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            else res.json(rates);
          });
      })
      .post((req,res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        let rate = new Rate(req.body);
        rate.save();
        res.status(201).send(rate);
      });
    return rateRouter;
}

module.exports = rateRoutes;
```

When I execute the post with {"rate": 26} I got 
{ '{\n        "rate" : "26"\n}': '' }

I read something about the order of bodyParser, but doesn't work.

Comment: how are you calling API?

Comment: I am calling with POSTMAN. And thank you because I think this is the problem. I was posting the data in raw but I have to use urlencoded. Now is working good... thank you!!

Comment: raw also you can pass you have to select json in the dropdown.